# How to disable audio jack detection Dell e7400 Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

I have a Dell e7400 (Win 10, 64bit) with broken headphone detection. The headphones are normally supposed to turn on when they're plugged in. However, i need to restart my computer with the headphones plugged in to have it detect the headphone and play sound via the audio jack.
I've tried updating the audio drivers many times wihtout luck.

Therefore I'd like to control this feature manually and force the sound to come out of my headphones all the time.

I've found registry keys that can be edited for Windows 10.

1. Press Windows Key + R.
2. Type regedit, press Enter.
3. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E96C-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0007\GlobalSettings.
4. Right-click the REG_BINARY EnableDynamicDevices, click Modify, and set it to 0.
5. Reboot.

I did not have the REG_BINARY EnableDynamicDevices in ' \0007\GlobalSettings', however, it was in '\0013\GlobalSettings'.
After changing to 0, and reboot, no difference.

I've read somewhere that this might be because my machine is still using the realtek driven and i would need the original windows 10 audio drivers.
"High Definition Audio" (native driver). Source: (https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Latitude-E7440-Sound-not-coming-through-headphones/td-p/4639683)

However, i've tried uninstalling the Realtek driver without succes and cannot find the windows driver for Dell e7400 on my machine/online.

Does anyone know how to get rid of the Realtek driver and/or change registry setting that even with realtek driver audio jack detection is turned off?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Login as administrator.
2. Then, click Start > Run.
3. On the Open field, type

> services.msc

and then click OK. The Services console pops up, listing all services that are installed on the computer.

4. Look for the Realtek service and disable it.

The reason: it seems like this service has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got the wrong device in the device manager, it should be under "Sound, video and game controllers." Click uninstall device and remove the driver file.

I did that and then searched for the class Guid in the details of the High Definition Audio Device, which points to the class you pasted. For me, it was under 0000, not 0007.

Now I have two separate devices without jack detection. (Dell Inspiron 3521)